# QGIS: Is there a way to make the "Python Console" a separate window?

Tags: qgis, qgis-python-console, mapcanvas

QGIS 3.10; Ubuntu 18.04

When Plugins->PythonConsole is accessed, it opens as a panel, changing the shape of the map canvas.

Can it be a separate window instead?

Alternatively, is there a way to run a python command; e.g., size() and resize(), without having to open the console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show a new window using the following

```py
from console.console import PythonConsoleWidget

consoleWidget = PythonConsoleWidget()
consoleWidget.show()
```

You could hide with `startup.py` original Python console in the menus and instead use this separated window. Be careful as my code does do manage the console as a singleton like the `show_console` used by default https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/console/console.py#L42 (and use a QDockWidget)

> Alternatively, is there a way to run a python command; e.g., size() and resize(), without having to open the console?

Normally, using again `startup.py` you could (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file) considering you will not need to use it after QGIS startup.